# Wrap specific lines in buffer

Tags: filetype-tex, wrapping, wrap

is it possible to `set nowrap` to a line range in the active buffer and `set wrap` to everything else?

I edit LaTeX files. I want to see everything after `\begin{document}`. but only see the general structure of the preamble.

I want this:

```
          Vim Window
  __________________________
||   \documentclass[a4paper,||21pt]{article}    > preamble
||   \usepackage[style=autho||ryear]{biblatex}  }
||   \title{Vim is Awesome} ||                  }
||   \renewcommand{\baseline||strech}{1.3}      }      set nowrap
||   \author{Noah Kuttler}  ||                  }
||                          ||                  }
||   \begin{document}       ||                  > \begin{document}
||     Soluta cum aut cupidi||                  ]
||tate velit. Dolor cup sulu||                  ]
||iditate voluptates r dlum ||                  ]
||pudiandae non beatae gara ||                  ] 
||et hic consectetur. lastem||                  ]      set wrap
||olestiae et dignissi pero ||                  ]
||os magnam quia quise.     ||                  ]
||    \end{document}        ||                  ]
||                          ||                  ]
||__________________________||
```

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this, and working around it with separate windows and whatnot might prove hard and cludgy.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Hi @D.BenKnoble so glad to be here!